# XBRL Module Not Recognized

Tags: python, pip, xbrl

I've downloaded the XBRL module using pip install. But the Python interpreter says "No module named 'xbrl'", despite the XBRL being present via C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages. How do I resolve this issue so I can run XBRL in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two Pythons? It could be you installed the module with one `pip/python` and tried to import with another `python`.

Anyway there is nothing to use: the module [`xbrl.py`](https://github.com/divbzero/xbrl/blob/c2e706fb8e75e870a3983e92408139de9e805457/xbrl.py) doesn't have any content. This `xbrl.py` is unusable, you should look for a different implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install python-xbrl.

Th easiest way is with pip :

pip install python-xbrl